# How to specify the day when using pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Say I have this dataframe:

```
Index      ID   V1  V2
00:00:00   K1   3   4
00:00:00   K2   4   3
00:00:00   K17  2   5
00:00:00   K11  8   6
```

and I want to turn the index into a date:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

This will assign the index column today's date:

```
Index                 ID   V1  V2
2019-02-18 00:00:00   K1   3   4
2019-02-18 00:00:00   K2   4   3
2019-02-18 00:00:00   K17  2   5
2019-02-18 00:00:00   K11  8   6
```

Is there any way I can assign a specific year-month-day string that does not change every time I generate the dataframe? The hour stamp must remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is convert values to timedeltas and add `Timestamp`:

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index) + pd.Timestamp('2015-01-20')
print (df)
             ID  V1  V2
Index                  
2015-01-20   K1   3   4
2015-01-20   K2   4   3
2015-01-20  K17   2   5
2015-01-20  K11   8   6
```

If necessary set new `Timestamp` same in all index values:

```
df.index = np.repeat(pd.Timestamp('2015-01-20'), len(df))
print (df)
             ID  V1  V2
2015-01-20   K1   3   4
2015-01-20   K2   4   3
2015-01-20  K17   2   5
2015-01-20  K11   8   6
```

---

Times are not displayed, because `0`, but each `Timestamp` contains it:

```
print (df.index.tolist())
[Timestamp('2015-01-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-01-20 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2015-01-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-01-20 00:00:00')]
```

Onkly way is repeat string representation of Timestamps:

```
df.index = np.repeat('2015-01-20 00:00:00', len(df))
print (df)
                      ID  V1  V2
2015-01-20 00:00:00   K1   3   4
2015-01-20 00:00:00   K2   4   3
2015-01-20 00:00:00  K17   2   5
2015-01-20 00:00:00  K11   8   6
```

Comment: Ok, but this will "delete" the hour stamp, which I need.

Comment: @FaCoffee - It is only display problem, check `print (df.index)`